# React Router V4 set active link with Server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-router-v4

When using react-router-dom NavLink + server side rendering.
Setting the 'activeClassName' prop on the client to other than an empty string, results a checksum error.

How can i set it on the server / Why is it not set by the component on the server

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Here is a link to the repository

Comment: https://github.com/giladl82/react-ssr-boilerplate